# How to store/display an SVG image in HTML with a CDN

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, svg

I have a rails application that uses a CDN to fetch assets in production. I'm trying to add SVG icons where the colours can be manipulated dynamically:

1. Example icon

```html
<svg width="90" height="45" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M36 34.3c5.5 0 9.9-4.5 9.9-10s-4.5-9.9-9.9-9.9H10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 9.9s4.5 10 10 10h26z"/>
    <g transform="translate(6.69 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(27.976 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(38.464 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

2. Icon with colour red set

```html
<svg width="90" height="45" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="red">
    <path d="M36 34.3c5.5 0 9.9-4.5 9.9-10s-4.5-9.9-9.9-9.9H10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 9.9s4.5 10 10 10h26z"/>
    <g transform="translate(6.69 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(27.976 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(38.464 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I only one want the paths without an existing `fill:` to be changed, everything else should remain as originally defined.

To ensure only one image file was fetched, I combined all 120 SVG icons into a sprite file using symbols to externally reference an icon e.g.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 90 45" id="trailer"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M36 34.3c5.5 0 9.9-4.5 9.9-10s-4.5-9.9-9.9-9.9H10c-5.5 0-10 4.5-10 9.9s4.5 10 10 10h26z"/>
    <g transform="translate(6.69 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(27.976 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(38.464 39.534)">
        <path d="M-5 0c0-2.8 2.2-5 5-5s5 2.2 5 5-2.2 5-5 5-5-2.2-5-5z" fill="#0a0a0a"/>
        <circle r="3.5" fill="#ccc"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  ...
</svg>

<svg fill="#0099FF">
  <use xlink:href="#trailer"></use>
</svg>
```

Now, this would have been completely fine for a production release, until I found a CORS issue around using external SVGs through a different domain:

https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/707

At this point in time *I think* my best bet it to either:

1. Include the SVG sprite into all HTML pages to allow for external references:

```
<head>
  <div style="display: none;" data-turbolinks-permanent>
      <!-- SVG Sprite -->
  </div>
</head>
<body>
  <svg fill="#0099FF">
    <use xlink:href="#trailer"></use>
  </svg>
</body>
```

(rails/turbolinks extra)

`data-turbolinks-permanent` marks the element as permanant across page since it won't be changing - https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads

2. Inject the SVG using https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject
3. Ajax the sprite, or better yet use service worker + ajax

https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/

https://www.clicktorelease.com/blog/optimise-svg-load-service-worker/

I'm swinging more towards point 1, as the application also generates PDF reports and it might be easier to avoid using JS to fetch images on report generation and keep things consistent.

I have also tried:

- using CSS `mask` but the whole icon colour changed
- creating the icons as a font instead - all colours were removed and everything could only be one colour

I just need to make sure there is no other possible options out there that I have yet to discover.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.